# Question on homotopic maps

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I was going through some introductory algebraic topology. The book I am reading says that:

If there is a homotopy $H: X\times I \rightarrow Y$ where $I = [0,1]$, then for each $t \in I$, there is a continuous map $h_t: X\rightarrow Y$ defined by

$$h_t(x) = H(x,t)  \text{for all }  x \in X$$

Now I was wondering how to show that this $h_t$ is continuous.

I know that $H$ is continuous by the definition of homotopy.

To prove $h_t$ is continuous, I will have to show that for each open set $U$ in $Y$, $h_t^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

How can I show that or is there any other method?

Please, help

Comment: The restriction of continuous function to any subset with subspace topology is also continuous. So $h_t = H|_{X \times \{t\}}$ is continuous.

Comment: $h_t$ is from X to Y while H|$_{X\times {t}}$ is from $X \times {t}$ to Y..how can they be equal?

Comment: I'm being sloppy. What I mean is like Lee Mosher's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the function $h_t : X \to Y$ as a composition of two continuous functions, and then apply the theorem that a composition of continuous function is continuous.

1. First, the function $X \to X \times [0,1]$ defined by $x \mapsto (x,t)$;
2. followed by the function $H : X \times [0,1] \to Y$.

Continuity of the second function $H$ is given to you. Continuity of the first function can, if you like, be easily proven using the open set definition, combined with the definition of the product topology on $X \times [0,1]$.

Comment: How to show that the first function is continuous?

Comment: Should I take a basic open set in X $\times$ [0,1] and look at its inverse image?

Comment: We are taking [0,1] as a subspace of R..right?

Comment: Now V $\times$ (a,b) $\times$ [0,1] is a basic open set in X $\times$ [0,1] where $V$ is any basic open set in $X$..It seems difficult to tackle

Comment: I calculated it.. The inverse image will be V only.. Right?

Answer (score 0):

If $U\subseteq Y$ is open, then $H^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X\times I$. Now $h_t^{-1}(U)=H^{-1}(U)\cap(X\times\{t\})$ is open in $X\times\{t\}$ by definition of the subspace topology.

Comment: ht  is from X to Y while H|$_{X×t}$ is from X×t to Y..how can they be equal?

Comment: Right; technically they are not equal, so we're identifying $X\times\{t\}$ with $X$ here.

Comment: How can you identify  that?.. I didn't get it.. Please give some details?

Comment: Are you trying to say use the fact that they are homeomorphic?

Comment: @Gitika yes that's what he means. Also, don't spam the comments. Just write a single comment with everything you want to say.